# PDFBox to export Annotation into FDF format

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to export the annotation of a PDF file into FDF format, which can be imported into another PDF file later.

I tried the example program(ExportFDF.java https://www.javatips.net/api/pdfbox-master/pdfbox-trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExportFDF.java) from PDFBox source documents. However, this java program just work for exporting a FDF file without annotation information. I wondered whether there is a way that I can export the annotation information into the FDF file directly?

Currently I was thinking to achieve this by two steps:

1. Extract annotation information (`getPages()`, `getRectangle()`, `getContents()`) into a txt file
2. Read the txt file and create the FDF file by program

I think this approach can work but I think there must be a way to combine the two steps (extract the annotation information and output as a FDF directly in one step).

Any suggestions?

Comment: The best would be to have some FDF or XFDF files created by Adobe and then to do the same. (I have seen some XFDF files and somebody helped us with an importer last year or so, but we don't have an exporter)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you so much for the information. In that case I will get rid of an exporter directly and find other solutions.